# Arranging "ranked" nodes of a graph symmetrically

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

I have Markov chains with a pair of absorbing states taken from the $n$-length strings formed from `{"H","T"}` for `n` at least 3 (generally 3 or 4), for example

```
{"HHH", "HHT", "HTH", "HTT", "THH", "THT", "TTH", "TTT"}
```

and with other states with names "leading up" to those states through the addition of either `"H"` or `"T"` to the end of the name of the previous state, from an initial state of `""`. For example the chain for the pair states `"TTH"` and `"HTT"` would have states

```
{"", "H", "T", "HT", "TT", "HTT", "TTH"}
```

I would like to represent the Markov chain for the transitions among these states as a graph with the nodes arranged according to their length as, for example in

[image]

but `Graph` does not arrange nodes this way by default,

[image]

and I can't figure out how to achieve a finer control over the node arrangement beyond what is offered by `GraphLayout` (though in some cases, as for this example, choosing `"LayeredDrawing"` comes close).

Is there a way that I can use the node names to order and align the arrangement of nodes in a `Graph` so that they appear as they do in the first figure: first `""`, then 1-length node names, then 2-length node names, etc.?

---

Ideally the approach should be able to take something like

```
mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, ( {
     {0, .5, 0, 0, .5, 0, 0},
     {0, .5, .5, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, .5, 0, .5, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, .5, 0, 0, 0, .5, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .5, .5},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    } )];
Graph[mp, VertexLabels -> {1 -> "", 2 -> "H", 3 -> "HT", 4 -> "HTT", 5 -> "T",  6 -> "TT", 7 -> "TTH"}]
```

and use `VertexLables` to automatically position the nodes in the `Graph` (the numbering and ordering of nodes is not guarantee, only the names). This should also work for "degenerate" cases such as

[image]

and for longer absorbing states such as

[image]

Comment: Your graph is relatively small and you need fine control over the appearance, possibly create a publication quality figure.  What I would do is export the graph to GraphML, import it into [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_helpresources.html), compute an automatic layout, then manually tweak it and manually add styling.  The node names are preserved and can be mapped to visual node labels in yEd.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I'm very much trying to avoid anything along that path. While each graph is small, I'm generating arbitrary graphs on the fly for interactively exploring and comparing them—e.g. with `someFuncIDefine["HHH", "TTT"]` which currently does all the work for me to build the appropriate Markov chain draw a labeled graph as in the second figure above. I need that function to go the next step and position the nodes as in the other figures. (If I weren't doing this I'd just draw them by hand and then use TikZ.)

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Do the graphs have a special structure that we can exploit to position the nodes "by hand"?  Writing a generic layout algorithm that also does what you want sounds hard.  Writing one that only works for special cases might be feasible.  Your example figures always have a Start node on the left, then precisely two rows of nodes above each other.  Are all of them like this?  Would it work to position the nodes in a grid (or maybe set of vertically centred columns) where the $n^\text{th}$ column contains length-$n$ nodes?

Comment: The edge routing would be more difficult, but we could still offload that task to an external but automatic tool (maybe GraphViz?  I don't have much experience with it but I know that it's much more flexible at edge routing than Mma).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Always 1 start node on the left, 2 at the right end (on top of each other), 2 at each each stage to the left of that, until there's just 1 and then 1 the rest of the way leftwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` with `"VertexPartition"->{1,1,2,2,...2}` for the `GraphLayout` option gives the desired layout:

```
mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 1/2, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1}}]; 
Graph[{"Start", "H", "HH", "HT", "HHT", "HTT"}, mp, ImageSize -> 600, 
        GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 1, 2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. For the general case, I'll need to make sure my states are sorted appropriately in constructing the `DiscreteMarkovChain`, which I think I can figure out how to do. Then I'll need to recognize where I have 2 and where I have one. Let me see if I'm clever enough.